# Update Database Column and Tables with Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, migrate

I've encounter into a situation where i try to update mysql database using django. here is the schema of it:
the original schema

```py
class Departments(models.Model):
    DepartmentId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    DepartmentName = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Groups(models.Model):
    GroupId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    GroupName = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Employees(models.Model):
    EmployeeID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    EmployeeName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Departments = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Groups = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    DateOfRecruitment = models.DateField()
    Position = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    PhotoFileName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

the new schema

```py
class Departments(models.Model):
    DepartmentId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    DepartmentName = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Groups(models.Model):
    GroupId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    GroupName = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Positions(models.Model):
    PositionId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    PositionName = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Employees(models.Model):
    EmployeeID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    EmployeeName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Departments = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Groups = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    DateOfRecruitment = models.DateField()
    DateOfResignation = models.DateField()
    Position = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Blacklist = models.BooleanField()
    BlacklistDate = models.DateField()
    PhotoFileName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I've tried to use the following command

```
python manage.py makemigrations someapp
python manage.py migrate
```

However it doesn't update within the mysql system itself. The only solution that i came out of is dropping the entire database and make the migration again. I hope that there is a better solution than my method as i couldn't just use the same method for data migration or another table update. Thank you.

Comment: What was the output of those two commands? What do you have in the newly generated migration file for `someapp`? (Based on the two schemata, you should have a new model and 3 new fields.)

Comment: that was the only respond : Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.

Comment: No, `makemigrations` will never say that. `migrate` might. We will need to see the outputs of both commands, and the new migration file that should have been generated in `someapp/migrations`.

Comment: @AKX i'm new to django at this point so do you have any youtube videos or article for that situation like this

Comment: No, I don't. I have these questions I'm trying to ask you so we can make sense of your situation.

Comment: according to makemigration command : No changes detected in app. but i've tried to delete the migration and resend the command but it still start doesn't work

Comment: Then you already have a migration file for those changes, and you have already applied all migrations. As I asked before, please show the migration file generated, in `someapp/migrations`. Also: how do you know "it doesn't update within the mysql system itself"? Are you sure you're looking in the right place?

Comment: the error is : No changes detected in app.

Comment: That's not an error. It means all migrations have been created (i.e. the migration files reflect the current state of your models), and "No migrations to apply" means there are no migrations that haven't been applied. Again: how do you know "it doesn't update within the mysql system itself"?

Comment: @AKX yes i tried to dot the api test using postman and it cannot find the the newly updated table of the database.

Comment: What do you mean with "postman cannot find the newly updated table"? _What error do you get there?_

Comment: I used Xampp ui to check the tables updated within the database itself but it still display the old schema. I build an api to test the respond of it for example i updated  a new table of Positions together with its new api.After Migrate and i run the get command of the api postman responded with there is no "position" table.

Comment: `makemigrations` will tell you it created a new migration with new fields if it works. `migrate` will apply that migration. If you haven't created a migration, no changes will occur. I also now noticed you edited your comment to say " i've tried to delete the migration" – you should never, ever delete a migration that may have already been applied to a database without unapplying it first (with `migrate appname <previousmigrationnumber>`), so if you have done that, your database may well be in an inconsistent state c.f. your models, which will require manual intervention.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `makemigrations` everytime you make even a small change in model's fields:

```
python manage.py makemigrations   # you don't have to use that: someapp
```

It should create some files in 'migrations' folder in any app, that has at least one difference. Only then second command will make change in database:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

Guessing by comments under question you probably haven't added your application to INSTALLED_APPS, thus why `makemigrations` doesn't detect changes.

Comment: actually i manage to import the new updated ones after dropping my entire database. and the INSTALLED_APPS had the app name in it.